# Changing accepted answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I noticed, today I got a `-15` rep change because a user unaccepted an answer, fair enough.

Surprise comes when I check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776728/spring-mvc-using-model-addattribute-in-controller-to-send-various-lists-to-a/29776867#29776867), and I've found the new [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776875/3850595) is not really an answer

> IMHO answer is no , you can't iterate or print the Arraylist inside the ÀJAX` response.
>   You can instead convert it into JSON-array and iterate it in the ajax response.

Also, it doesn't have much relation with the question that asks about attributes in a model. It seems more to be answering a comment that asks for further info for future users:

> Cool. Thanks. I will then use Array or JsonList. Just one thing, I know how to iterate through an array or convert list to array, but some other user in future might now, if you can write some pseudo code for future users.

Don't really mind the rep change, but should I do something in order to preserve quality of the site?

Answer (score 9):

It's entirely the prerogative of the OP to accept any answer they deem most suitable. Perhaps they did not understand your answer entirely and found the other one to be <strike>nicely dumbed down</strike> more comprehensible. Or [Tim lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/476) or something.

If the other answer is demonstrably bad or wrong, vote and comment on it appropriately; those are the quality control tools. If it's merely meh, then there's no reason to do anything.

Comment: fool... OP changed accepted answer again...  definitelly [Tim lost the keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) xDDD